# Scroll UITableView change data on UITextField stored in NSUserDefault

Tags: uitableview, scroll, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I've a TableView with TextField for each row. The TableView is composed by two section.
When the user tap on return button of KeyBoard, I set the text of TextField on NSUserDefault.
In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method i read the value of text on NSUserDefault.
Why when I scroll the TableView, the data changes?

On `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {        
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

//set cell value from NSArray
if ((indexPath.section) == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [sicurezzaSullaStrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoVeicolo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


//set TextField value from NSUserDefault
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    //first section
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        TextFieldCell = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 21)];
        TextFieldCell.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        TextFieldCell.placeholder = @"Enter text";
        TextFieldCell.delegate = self;
        [TextFieldCell setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringPesoKg"]];
        cell.accessoryView = TextFieldCell;
        }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        TextFieldCell = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 21)];
        TextFieldCell.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        TextFieldCell.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
        TextFieldCell.delegate = self;
        [TextFieldCell setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringPostiLettoOmologati"]];
       cell.accessoryView = TextFieldCell;
    } else {
    //second section
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //Riga relativa alla Data di immatricolazione
        TextFieldCell = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 21)];
        TextFieldCell.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        TextFieldCell.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
        TextFieldCell.delegate = self;
        [TextFieldCell setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringDataImmatricolazione"]];
        cell.accessoryView = TextFieldCell;
    }
```

And then on`textFieldDidEndEditing`:

```
if (posizSect == 0) {
    if (posizRow == 0) {
        NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultPesoKg = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [stringDefaultPesoKg setObject:textField.text forKey:@"stringPesoKg"];  
    }
    if (posizRow == 1) {
        NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultPostiLettoOmologati = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [stringDefaultPostiLettoOmologati setObject:textField.text forKey:@"stringPostiLettoOmologati"];  
    }
    if (posizRow == 2) {
        NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultPostiLettoOmologati = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [stringDefaultPostiLettoOmologati setObject:textField.text forKey:@"stringLunghezzaMax"];  
    } else {
    if (posizRow == 0) {
        NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultPesoKg = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [stringDefaultPesoKg setObject:textField.text forKey:@"stringDataImmatricolazione"];  
    }
```

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I set the value of PosizRow and PosizSect:

```
posizRow = indexPath.row;
posizSect = indexPath.section;
```

Thanks,
Alessandro from Italy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the data changes, is that the UITableViewCells get dequeued when you scroll them off the screen.  The data is then gone at this point, and when you scroll back, the cell is repopulated with the initial values (not the changed ones).  I don't know how to fix it, I am looking for that solution now.  When I find it, I'll link you to it.

*EDIT***
Ok here is what you do:

First, you need to make your ViewController a delegate for UITextFieldDelegate.  Then you need to implement:

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

In my case, the user interface is done dynamically in code, so I Have an NSMutableDictionary that contains the names of all of the fields.  So in my code I do the following:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSArray *fields = [editTexts allKeysForObject:textField];

    if(fields.count > 0)
    {
        [clonedItem setValue:textField.text forKey:[fields objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}
```

If you have your text fields as properties then you'll need another way to update your storage variable.  For instance, you might use a tag on the textField to identify which field.